# Change the name of the FontSize Dropdown list in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

So I'm using TinyMCE and I'd like to allow the user to change the Font Size to one predefined size (larger).

I've managed to do that with this custom setting:

```
font_size_style_values: "large,x-small,small,medium,large,x-large,xx-large",
theme_advanced_font_sizes: "1",
```

However, in the font size select drop down list, the text that appears is "1 (8pt)", which is not very user friendly.

I'd like to change this to "large", or anything really. Any ideas?

Here are my complete custom settings, if that helps:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "exact",
    elements: "Details", // "EventDetails_Directions, EventDetails_Details"
    width: "673",
    height: "320",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "paste, media",
    autocomplete: "off",
    convert_fonts_to_spans : true,
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,justifyleft,justifycenter,fontsizeselect,link,unlink,image,bullist,separator,undo,redo,code",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    font_size_style_values: "large,x-small,small,medium,large,x-large,xx-large",
    theme_advanced_font_sizes: "1",
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
    paste_remove_styles: true,
    paste_retain_style_properties: "none",
    paste_strip_class_attributes: "all",
    paste_preprocess: function(p1, o) {
        o.content = replaceWordChars(o.content);
    },
    content_css: "/ClientControlRoom/assets/css/tinymce_custom.css"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [theme_advanced_font_sizes](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atheme_advanced_font_sizes) config option since TinyMCE 3.2 has allowed you to map a text value to the font size (pixel or relative) or a class.

So if you only want one option ("large") for you users in the drop down, you could have

```
theme_advanced_font_sizes : "large=30px"
```

or, if you are using relative sizes simple

```
theme_advanced_font_sizes : "large"
```

Comment: Thanks man! I thought you had to have exactly 7 items in that list, and switch them on and off with theme_advanced_font_sizes. You're a prince among men. On other news, TinyMCE is a great editor and the business really like using it.